# How do I update the root CA certificate for Acrobat?

Tags: certificate, adobe-acrobat, trusted-root-ca

We had a name change recently and verified a new certificate with the new name appears in the domain root CA but Acrobat and the local computer cert store do not have this new certificate.  I'm not finding much information online for managing this kind of setup.  I believe the certificate is generated by AD.

How do I get Acrobat or the computer to load the new certificate from the domain root CA?

Comment: Have you installed the new certificate on the system and delete the old certificate?

Comment: I have not.  I have never dealt with certificates before.  Shouldn't they update on their own if generated by AD?  If not do I just export the cert from the CA then install on the workstation?

Comment: You said you only believe the certificate was generated by the AD.

Comment: The ones on everyone's computers say issued by the Root CA and they got there automatically.  Is that an AD thing?  That's where things get fuzzy for me.  We did not put them on the computers or create them.  What would be the normal process for a name change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Ramhound I exported the certificate from the root CA and imported it into the user's machine under `Certificates - Current User/Personal/Certificates` where the wrongly named certificate was stored.  At this point Acrobat did not show the new certificate.

I then right clicked the certificate and went to `All Tasks > Request Certificate With New Key`.  This generated/imported a new certificate of the same name with an expiration one year from today.

I deleted the now duplicated certificate I imported and Acrobat is now showing both certificates with the old name and new name.

I was afraid to break something so I did not try requesting a certificate with a new key using the old name certificate.  I'm curious what would happen if it would still have the old name or not.